# Can I send pre-computed and pickle-saved embeddings into DocArrayInMemorySearch?

Tags: chatbot, langchain

In my chatbot that I developed with Langchain, PDFs are indexed from the beginning every time the program runs, and this is a cost. I thought about recording this process and sending it to DocArrayInMemorySearch as doc and embedding, but of course it didn't work. Is there anyone working on this? I would be very happy if it helps